# Feature Engineering for Improving correlation between features and result

Tags: python, pandas, regression, feature-selection

how can I improve correlation between features and result so  that I can implement regression models?
I know that with pandas .corr() function I can see correlation, and that best features for regression models are the one that are closest to 1 or -1. But what should I do if all features are close to 0?
Is there a way to implement some kind of feature engineering so that I can improve this correlation?

This is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'par 1':[1,3,2,5,7,4,6,1,3,1,1,2,4],
                   'par 2':[5,4,3,1,5,3,1,3,5,3,5,7,9],
                   'par 3':[1,3,3,4,5,1,5,2,5,9,5,7,9],
                   'result':[11,9,10,12,11,23,13,16,18,18,20,22,25]})

cor = df.corr()
print(cor['result'].sort_values())
```

Comment: You only want high correlations between "features" and "result" - not correlations between features and other features (these should be independent). If there are no correlations, consider a non-linear model - DecisionTree / RandomForest for example

Comment: Yeah I meant correlation between features and result, so there isnt some kind of experimental preprocessing that I can do, or something like that?

Comment: You can't _improve_ the correlation between features. That's like saying "I want to make these apples more like oranges." There is a ***lot*** of preprocessing you can do with your data, but your question, as it stands, doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: This is probably a more opinionated question and it's mainly a lot of trial and error, but you could look into scikit.learn [PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) as a starter for 10

Comment: Couldn't tell if your question was based on the df you provided, but the correlations in the sample df you provided aren't **that** close to zero. Two were around 0.5 and one about -.2. I wouldn't say these are necessarilly unmeaningful correlations. The features' correlations may or may not be more strongly associated with your result if you try using log transormations, polynomials, etc. Like @ChrisA said, you'll have to try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Most correlation analysis like Pearson, etc. generates a score based on **linear** correlation, but you can have features that correlate in a non-linear way and get an R score close to 0. The best way to handle such cases is to generate a scatter plot of the feature and the target. If the scatter-plot shows noise, then the feature is useless and should be discarded. If the scatter-plot shows a non-linear pattern, then try transforming the feature value X using log(X), sqrt(X), X^2, X^3, etc, until the scatter-plot shows a linear correlation. You can then validate this using Pearson, etc.